# Change if sentences to a switch conditional in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I am working with PyQT6. I am trying to get the text from checkbox that change a label, for example `"You have selected: " + value`. So the question is, how to convert these if conditionals to a switch case?

Here is the method of the if conditionals

```
    def item_selected(self):
        value = ""
        if self.check1.isChecked():
            value = self.check1.text()

        if self.check2.isChecked():
            value = self.check2.text()

        if self.check3.isChecked():
            value = self.check3.text()

        if self.check4.isChecked():
            value = self.check4.text()

        self.label.setText("You have selected: " + value)
```

How to implement this code with switch case?
I tried this:

```
    def item_selected(self):
        value = ""

        match value:
            case bool(self.check1.isChecked()):
                value = (self.check1.text())
            case bool(self.check2.isChecked()):
                value = (self.check2.text())
            case bool(self.check3.isChecked()):
                value = (self.check3.text())
            case bool(self.check4.isChecked()):
                value = (self.check4.text())
        self.label.setText("You have selected: " + value)
```

but I'm not getting the values when I check the boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this expression can be converted to switch-conditional since it is based on the state of a variable. Also if you want to reduce the expression then you can do it with a for-loop:

```py
value = ""

for checkbox in (self.check4, self.check3, self.check2, self.check1):
    if checkbox.isChecked():
        value = checkbox.text()
        break

self.label.setText(f"You have selected: {value}")
```

Comment: This is a good solution because my last objective was to reduce the expression. I am so used to C, so I thought I needed a switch case for 4 ifs, but for me this is the solution, thank you.